# how to sort data in datatables with no

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

i want to sort the data in the datatables with numeric function in both ways ascending and descending. i used the following codebut was not working.

```
$('#data_table').dataTable( {
    "aaData": dataSet,
    "aaSorting": [[1,'asc','desc'],[3,'asc','desc']],
    "iDisplayLength": 4,                
    "bInfo": true,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bPaginate": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bAutoWidth": true,
    "aoColumns": [
        {   
            "sTitle": "Seller", 
            "sClass": "grey" ,
            "fnRender": function(obj) {
                var data = obj.aData[ obj.iDataColumn ];
                return "<A href='"+ data.url +"'>"+ data.title +"</A>";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean that you want to sort both ways? aaSorting is used to sort the table on inizialization so

```
 "aaSorting": [[1,'asc','desc'],[3,'asc','desc']],
```

is not valid you should do (for example):

```
 "aaSorting": [[1,'asc'],[3,'desc']],
```

This would sort the table on the first pass with ascending sorting on the second column and descending sorting on the fourth column.

Comment: sorry , but its not working. Its not sorting the data in the coulmns correctly. And i want the data to be sorted in the both the ways ascending and descding in each columns.

Comment: i want whole no to be sorted and this is sorting data on the first didgit of the data

Answer (score 0):

unable to understand, do u want to sort same column in both asc and desc order

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['string-case-asc']  = function(x,y) {
return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ?  1 : 0));};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['string-case-desc'] = function(x,y) {
return ((x < y) ?  1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));};
```

check [this](http://datatables.net/development/sorting#)